# How to select single xml tag from multiple xml tags in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

This is HTML file (namestore.html):--

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Ajax Practice</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="namestore.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div  onkeyup="process()">
    Enter your name:<input type="text"  id="userInput"/>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="outputMsg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is PHP file (namestore.php):--

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<xtag>';
    $x = 1;
echo '</xtag>';

echo '<response>';
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $nameArray = array('Raj','John','Sam','Mac');

    if(in_array($name,$nameArray))
    {
        echo 'Wasup'.' '. $name;
    }
    elseif($name=='')
    {
        echo 'Enter a name pal!';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Your name is not in our list.';
    }
echo '</response>';

echo '<ytag>';
    $y = 2;
echo '</ytag>';

echo '<ztag>';
    $z = 3;
echo '</ztag>'; ?>
```

This is JAVASCRIPT file (namestore.js):--

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
    var xmlHttp;
    if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp)
        alert("Object not created....");
    else
        return xmlHttp;
}

function process()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "namestore.php?name=" +name, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handelResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }   
}

function handelResponse()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        if(xmlHttp.status==200)
        {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            document.getElementById("outputMsg").innerHTML = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("response")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Something is wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to fetch data from `<response>...</response>` tag from namestore.php in namestore.js.
How can get data from `<response>...</response>` tag.

Please help...